# Regex pattern for period separator and no comma Angular 2

Tags: regex, angular2-forms, angular-reactive-forms

What would the Regex pattern be in Angular 2 Reactive forms for values that could be whole or decimal but with a period (fullstop) as a separator.

```
10.25 //valid
100 //valid
10.2344555 //valid
10,20 //invalid
```

I have the following which is almost there but allows for the comma seperator as well

```
 income: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?')]],
```

Regards

Comment: Use `'[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?'`

Comment: /^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/

Comment: I have created a library on comma seperator, which can be used with formcontrol only. It is a directive to format the model value which will appear in the view. It will not manipulate the Input value which will be saved in the model. See link [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-format-field) To see the demo: [here](https://angular-ydfct6.stackblitz.io/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use

```
income: ['', [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('[0-9]+(?:\\.[0-9]+)?')]],
```

This will be translated into [`/^[0-9]+(?:\.[0-9]+)?$/` regex](https://regex101.com/r/KP7ads/1) that matches 1+ digits followed with an optional sequence of `.` and then 1+ digits.